# How to access an element of an array just given a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
struct node
{
  int a;
  node * link;
}
```

i have an array A with each element of type 'pointer to node' and hence each element of A can have variable size.Example

```
A[0]=NULL
A[1]=2->3->4
A[2]=3->4
```

and so on..
so to dynamically allocate an array if I use

```
u = (struct node*) malloc( m * sizeof(struct node*) )
```

then

```
u+i = NULL
```

(i is any integer) gives error as Lvalue required.
If I use array pointer as

```
struct node(*p)[];
```

and then use

```
 (*p)+i = NULL
```

it gives error as L value required.

```
*(p+i) = NULL
```

gives error as
invalid use of array with unspecified bounds

What is the solution?

Comment: `u+i = NULL` --> `*(u+i) = NULL` or `u[i] = NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node;

struct node{
    int a;
    node * link;
};

void print(node *np){
    while(np){
        printf("%d->", np->a);
        np = np->link;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main(){
    struct node four  = {4, NULL};
    struct node three = {3, &four};
    struct node two   = {2, &three};

    struct node **u;
    int m = 3;
    u = malloc(m * sizeof(struct node*));
    u[0] = NULL;
    u[1] = &two;
    u[2] = &three;
    for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
        print(u[i]);
    free(u);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
(*p) += i;
(*p) = NULL;
```

or

```
p[i] = NULL;
```

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_node {
  int x;
  struct s_node *next;      
} node ;


main()
{   
    node n[5];

    n[2].x = 42;
    printf("%d\n", n[2].x);

    node *p = n;    
    printf("%d\n", p[2]);

    p += 2;    
    printf("%d\n", p->x);
}
```

Output:

```
42
42
42
```

Consider to take a look at a [tutorial for pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm). Just google for it or click the provided link.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have to carry on all the allocations dynamically and that is creating whole of the problem.
can you please do it using dynamic allocation somewhat like my question above.

Comment: I think you should reformulate your question. I thought you were asking about the L-value error.